# Find the roots of the quadratic $2$ by $2$ Hermitian matrix equation

Tags: quadratics, matrix-equations

I want to find the roots of the quadratic $2$ by $2$ hermitian matrix equation, which has the following form
$$
X\Delta X + X\Lambda + \Lambda X - \Delta^{\dagger} = 0
$$
where $\Delta^{\dagger}$ is the Hermitian matrix of $\Delta$, and $\Lambda$ is a Hermitian matrix. Both $\Lambda$ and $\Delta$ are $2$ by $2$ matrices. So could I find the solution of the equation? What's the explicit expression of $X$?

Comment: If you know Kronecker products, it can help greatly. If not, then I think finding ways to expressing solutions will be much harder.

Comment: are the known and unknown matrices real ?

Comment: @loupblanc: Here we consider the complex matrix. But as a first step, you could give you answer for real matrix.

Comment: @Roger209 , the use on this website is, if one is satisfied with an answer, to upvote  it and  -or- to attribute the green chevron to it. If you are not satisfied, say why.

Answer (score 1):

$Z^*$ denotes the transconjugate of $Z$ and, by a change of notations, we consider the equation

$(*)$ $XAX+XS+SX-A^*$ where $S$ is hermitian.

$(*)$ is a particular Riccati equation. We consider the associated pseudo Hamiltonian matrix: $M=\begin{pmatrix}-S&-A\\-A^*&S\end{pmatrix}$; note that $M$ is hermitian and therefore is diagonalizable and has only real eigenvalues but the eigenvectors are not real (in general).

**We consider only the generic case when $M$ has $4$ distinct eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)_i$. Then $(*)$ has exactly $6$ distinct solutions.

In the above conditions, the $6$ $M$-invariant spaces of dimension $2$ are the $(span(e_i,e_j))_{1\leq i<j\leq 4}$ where $e_i$ is "the" eigenvector associated to $\lambda_i$.

At $span(e_i,e_j)$, we associate the matrix $[e_i,e_j]=\begin{pmatrix}U_{2,2}\\V_{2,2} \end{pmatrix}$ and finally, one of the $6$ required  solutions $X_{i,j}=VU^{-1}$.  $\square$

Remark 1. If $A,S$ are real, then all solutions in $X$ are real.

Remark 2. The principal part of the calculation is to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$. That is, essentially, to solve a polynomial of degree $4$.

Comment: Chould you please show me the explicit solution, if any? I mean, a formula like Vieta theorem.

Comment: @Roger209   No kidding...  I will not answer your questions any more.

Comment: I am sorry. The aim of the post is to find the explicit solution, rather than the theoretical analysis. While I admit that this may be still an ongoing research topic, I prefer the answers that include the explicit solution, or under what circumstances shall we have the explicit solution. For example, the case $\Delta$=$\Lambda$, or $\Delta$=$\textbf{I}$.